XSLT transformation of fixed length file into xml with irregular spaces in each line
In the file I have fixed length lines but each line has some empty spaces which may be different as below
01474011240229GASOHOL   000000+000000+0006500064640009987
01474021240216SUPER     001000+001000+0000852011700006022
while transforming into xml the white space are reduced to only one space which messes up the substring calculation after white spaces
for example I need first five characters and highlighted substring above but the highlighted substring comes different

I tried to use translate to convert space into - so i can count them and move forward but it puts only one - for all empty space and still does not solve the problem.
This is the output coming

below is xslt  string i am using
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xslextnobjects="urn:xsl-extn-objects">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"
      omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:include href="shared_csv_to_xml.xsl"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="ParsedCsvRow">
         <xsl:call-template name="splitNewLine">
            <xsl:with-param name="str" select="."/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:call-template name="GenerateTransformedOutput">
         <xsl:with-param name="CsvRowData">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$ParsedCsvRow"/>
         </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template name="GenerateTransformedOutput">
      <xsl:param name="CsvRowData"/>
      <xsl:element name="pseudoRoot">
         <xsl:element name="altFeedIntermediateSchema">
            <xsl:element name="businessDate">
               <xsl:text>0001-01-01T01:01:01.0001-06:00</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
         </xsl:element>
         <xsl:element name="altFeedIntermediateSchema">
            <xsl:element name="businessDate">
               <xsl:text>0001-01-01T01:01:01.0001-06:00</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
         </xsl:element>
         <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($CsvRowData)/record">
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="position() = 0"/>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:element name="altFeedIntermediateSchema">
                     <xsl:element name="siteIdentifier">
                        <xsl:value-of select="xslextnobjects:Substring(./column1, 0, 5)"/>
                     </xsl:element>
                     <xsl:element name="tankIdentifier">
                        <xsl:value-of select="xslextnobjects:Substring(./column1, 0, 7)"/>
                     </xsl:element>
                     <xsl:element name="businessDate">
                        <xsl:value-of
                           select="xslextnobjects:ConvertDateTimeOffsetFormat(substring(./column1, 9, 6), 'yyMMdd', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffff')"
                        />
                     </xsl:element>
                     <xsl:element name="sales">
                        <xsl:value-of
                           select="xslextnobjects:GetNullableDouble(substring(xslextnobjects:ReplaceText(./column1, ' ', '-'), 38, 6))"
                        />
                     </xsl:element>
                     <xsl:element name="closeVolume">
                        <xsl:value-of
                           select="xslextnobjects:GetNullableDouble(substring(xslextnobjects:ReplaceText(./column1, ' ', '-'), 44, 5))"
                        />
                     </xsl:element>
                     <xsl:element name="productIdentifier">
                        <xsl:value-of select="translate(./column1, ' ', '-')"/>
                     </xsl:element>
                     <xsl:element name="deliveryGrossVolume">
                        <xsl:value-of
                           select="xslextnobjects:GetNullableDouble(substring(xslextnobjects:ReplaceText(./column1, ' ', '-'), 24, 6))"
                        />
                     </xsl:element>
                  </xsl:element>
               </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


"while transforming into xml the white space are reduced to only one space" XSLT does not transform a text file into XML (certainly not XSLT 1.0), so your question seems wrongly tagged.

sorry was not sure of the version.

Still, it seems the problem is created before the XSL transformation takes place. If not, please edit your question and provide a way to reproduce the problem - i.e. show an example input, your current stylesheet and the expected output (all as code, not pictures) - see: minimal reproducible example. And knowing the version of XSLT is important, too.

I guess the critical code is probably the included stylesheet module shared_csv_to_xml.xsl which you haven't actually shown us.

Are those spaces maybe tabs?
